# How can i create layered struct in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, class, orm

I'm learning C# & ASP.NET.

I'm trying to make a struct, I don't know is it ok call it ORM.

I have a database (using Entity Framework), and I try to separate SQL queries from aspx's codebehinds.

I've got 4 tables in my database (Kitaplar,Musteriler,Kiralamalar,Turler)
in my Kitaplar table I have got 8 field (KitapID(FK),KitapAdi,ISBN,Yayinevi,Yazaradi,Basimtarihi,Stok,TurTurID).

I created a class `Kitapmodel.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace KütüphaneYonetimSistemi.Models
{
    public class KitapModel
    {
        public int KitapID { get; set; }
        public string KitapAdı { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
        public string Yayınevi { get; set; }
        public string YazarAdı { get; set; }
        public DateTime BasimTarihi { get; set; }
        public int Stok { get; set; }
        public int TurTurID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I also created `kitapModelProvider.cs` for database connection and other things At this is the point I'm stuck.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace KütüphaneYonetimSistemi.Providers
{
    public class kitapModelProvider
    {
    }



    public KitapModel getByKitapID(int ID)
    {
        KutuphaneYonetimDB db = new KutuphaneYonetimDB();
        KitapModel bookListEF = from k in db.Kitaplar
                         join t in db.Turler
                         on k.TurTurID equals t.TurID
                         select new
                         {
                             k.KitapAdı,
                             k.YazarAdı,
                             t.TurAdı,
                             k.Yayınevi,
                             BasimTarihi = k.BasimTarihi.ToString().Replace(" 12:00AM", "").Replace("Jan", "Ocak").Replace("Feb", "Şubat").Replace("Mar", "Mart").Replace("Jun", "Haziran").Replace("Sep", "Eylül").Replace("Nov", "Kasım").Replace("Oct", "Aralık").Replace("Apr","Nisan"),
                             k.ISBN,
                             k.Stok
                         };
         return bookListEF;
    }

    public void insertKitap(KitapModel kitap)
    {
        KutuphaneYonetimDB db = new KutuphaneYonetimDB();
        db.Kitaplar.Add(kitap);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    /*
        other methods
    */
}
```

And in my `createBook.aspx.cs` file I want to do something like `this`;

```
KitapModel kitap = new Kitapmodel {
kitapAdi = "Harry Potter ve Felsefe Taşı",
ISBN = ......
Yayınevi....
...
Stok = 5,
TurTurID = 1 }
kitapModelProvider.insertKitap(kitap) // or kitapModel.insertKitap
```

Comment: It sounds like your question really is "How do I use Entity Framework?"  Specifically it looks like you want to build a repository with Entity Framework.  There are tutorials and examples to get you started with that.

Comment: I think you rather want to say How can i use `ORM` which would be off-topic to stackoverflow. First you need to know which ORM you are going to use ADO.NET - LINQ2SQL - EF and others... are available. choose one and start searching about them and their CRUD operations, that would be a good start. Also Entity framework is not a Database. It's an ORM.

Comment: I can use Entity Framework(or I think I can) but I use it in codebehind and this is what I dont want. I can populate entity framework DB connections but I dont know how to make connections with my classes

Comment: @AhmetKarabulut there are a *lot* of tutorials that explain how to use Entity Framework, including [EF's own documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx) and the [ASP.NET MVC tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: I think I cant clearly tell my problem because of my bad english. I want to know how can I make layered struct. I dont want to learn how can I use EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay since you are new to programming on ASP.NET, I try to put you on a right path.

**First What is an ORM :**

[From wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping):

> Object-relational mapping (ORM, O/RM,
>   and O/R mapping) in computer software
>   is a programming technique for
>   converting data between incompatible
>   type systems in relational databases
>   and object-oriented programming
>   languages. This creates, in effect, a
>   "virtual object database" that can be
>   used from within the programming
>   language. There are both free and
>   commercial packages available that
>   perform object-relational mapping,
>   although some programmers opt to
>   create their own ORM tools.

It's good for abstracting the data-store (SQL Databases / NoSQL Databases and so on) out in order to provide an interface that can be used in your code. Commonly used ORMs within .NET for Connecting to SQL are:

- ADO.NET
- LINQ To SQL
- ADO.NET Entity Framework

Now You've choosen EF (Entity Framework) as Object-relational mapping [ORM]. Second Step would be learning basics of EF Which you can Find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx).

**EF Provides 2 type of approaches:**

- Code-First

Where you would provide the POCO classes and their mapping And EF would create the table designs for you within the dbcontext class's OnBuildingMethod().

- Database-First

Traditional way to create table designs then you connect your database to your application and add a `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` and using it's wizard you call all of your tables and create their POCOs for you.

After You've learned About these and how it does work, you need to know about The [EF CRUD Operations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/entity-framework5-introduction.aspx).

And in the end you can start look at [Repository Pattern](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/03/07/how-to-implement-the-repository-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx) And [Unit of Work Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) using EF.

Comment: Thanks for your leading. I will look these link.